# Changing primeng CSS at component level

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I understand similar topics have been discussed multiple times, but I couldn't find the solution to the problem I am facing.

I am trying to change the styles of PrimeNG in my angular app.

In my component, I changed `.ui-inputext` class of PrimeNG.

```
    body .ui-inputtext {
    font-size: 0.8vw;
    padding:0;
    background-color: #557db1 !important;
}
```

This is working only when I set `encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None` in my component class.

I also tried using `:host >>>`

```
 :host >>>   body .ui-inputtext {
    font-size: 0.8vw;
    padding:0;
    color:red;
    background-color: #557db1 !important;
}
```

**Issue with using** `encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None` in my component is that it changes styles of PrimeNGcontrols in the whole app.

I want to make changes to the control only for this component where I have modified CSS class.

Is there something else I need to do or maybe I am missing something here?

This issue was raised on GitHub here (https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/1812) but it was not tracked further.

Comment: Given the comment on the GitHub issue, I presume you already searched on forums?

Comment: It was closed on github.

Comment: Yes, that wasn't my question. The person on GitHub said to use forums. I'm asking you if you've searched those forums.

Comment: Apologies. Yes I did, I didnt find anything relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Add one class to that input field and try to change css using that class rather than using the body and add `encapsulation: Viewencaptulation.None` in your component.ts file. It will not change other component css.

Here is the example code you can try like this:

```
<input type="text" class="field_input" pInputText placeholder="Username">

.field_input.ui-inputtext {
  font-size: 0.8vw;
  padding:0;
  background-color: #557db1 !important;
}
```

Stackblitz Link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-romzcu?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: using encaptulation: Viewencaptulation.None changing style in all components.

Comment: If you change css using unique class name instead of  body then it will not changing style in all components

Comment: Can you provide a stackbiltz? That would be very helpful.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-romzcu?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts stackblitz Link

Comment: Primeng uses input html tag, which makes it easier for us to change styles, can you do something similar with p-dropdown element. Sorry to bother you with this, but that's where I am stuck at. You are free to ignore though.

Comment: It will also work for dropdown or any primeng element. you can try this.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `:host /deep/` in your component css file.

Comment: I tried, it didn't work. Can you provide a stackbiltz if it is working for you?